# How to set label for each subplot in a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

let's think i have four features in a dataset and plotting scatter 
plots using two features each time.I want to provide label to each 
plot separately.

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots(ncols=2,figsize=(10,8))
axes[0].scatter(x1,x2],marker="o",color="r")
axes[1].scatter(x3,x4,marker="x",color="k")
axes[0].set(xlabel="Exam score-1",ylabel="Exam score-2")
axes[1].set(xlabel="Exam score-1",ylabel="Exam score-2")
axes[0].set_label("Admitted")
axes[1].set_label("Not-Admitted")
axes.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here I will get two scatter plots but labels are not shown. I want 
to see **admitted** as label for first plot and **not-admitted** 
for second scatter plot.

I am able to give label by using `plt.legend()` but not getting already created plots.

Answer (score 26):

You are setting the label for the axes, not the scatters.

The most convenient way to get a legend entry for a plot is to use the `label` argument.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.random.rand(2,23)

fig,axes=plt.subplots(ncols=2)
axes[0].scatter(x,y, marker="o", color="r", label="Admitted")
axes[1].scatter(x,y, marker="x", color="k", label="Not-Admitted")
axes[0].set(xlabel="Exam score-1", ylabel="Exam score-2")
axes[1].set(xlabel="Exam score-1", ylabel="Exam score-2")

axes[0].legend()
axes[1].legend()
plt.show()
```

If you want to set the label after creating the scatter, but before creating the legend, you may use `set_label` on the `PathCollection` returned by the `scatter`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.random.rand(2,23)

fig,axes=plt.subplots(ncols=2)
sc1 = axes[0].scatter(x,y, marker="o", color="r")
sc2 = axes[1].scatter(x,y, marker="x", color="k")
axes[0].set(xlabel="Exam score-1", ylabel="Exam score-2")
axes[1].set(xlabel="Exam score-1", ylabel="Exam score-2")

sc1.set_label("Admitted")
sc2.set_label("Not-Admitted")

axes[0].legend()
axes[1].legend()
plt.show()
```

Finally you may set the labels within the legend call:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.random.rand(2,23)

fig,axes=plt.subplots(ncols=2)
sc1 = axes[0].scatter(x,y, marker="o", color="r")
sc2 = axes[1].scatter(x,y, marker="x", color="k")
axes[0].set(xlabel="Exam score-1", ylabel="Exam score-2")
axes[1].set(xlabel="Exam score-1", ylabel="Exam score-2")

axes[0].legend([sc1], ["Admitted"])
axes[1].legend([sc2], ["Not-Admitted"])
plt.show()
```

In all three cases, the result will look like this:

[image]